# Is there a way to translate a Fusion 360 model to Inventor without creating an App?

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

From [Translate a Source File into OBJ Format](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-to-obj/):

> **Before You Begin**
>
> - Register an app
> - Successfully acquire an OAuth token with the `data:write` and `data:read` scopes.
> - Upload a source file to OSS, as described in the Create an App-Managed Bucket and Upload a File tutorial, and note the source URN.

I assume that the above steps are to be followed to translate a Fusion 360 model to an Inventor model.

I find it very inconvenient to create an App for the sole purpose of translating a Fusion 360 model to Inventor. I would like to avoid creating such an App.

Is there a way to translate/export a Fusion 360 model to Inventor without creating an App or without using the interactive web interface? If there is, can you please answer with the steps and/or point to a place where I can find that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, converting a Fusion 360 model to Inventor file format is only possible interactively on the A360 website at the moment.

Fusion 360 does have an [API](http://help.autodesk.com/view/NINVFUS/ENU/) (see ExportManager object) but it only exposes those file formats which the desktop app can convert to directly, and are available through File >> Export:
[image: Fusion 360 File Export]

Converting from Fusion 360 to Inventor file format might be possible through the Forge API's later on, but still, you'd have to register an App on the [Forge developer site](https://developer.autodesk.com) in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion here - the Autodesk Forge API is not meant to translate from Fusion360 to Inventor today (as August 22nd, 2016). We may add this possibility later, but Fusion360 can import from/export to Inventor native. Checkout [this post for more details](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/post-your-tips-and-tutorials/data-exchange-in-fusion-360-build-2-0-1291/td-p/5335113), it contains a lot of details on how to import or export as well as the format supported. Hope that helps,

Comment: That seems to be an interactive process. Is there a way to do that using a script?

Comment: Fusion360 has a C++/Python/Javascript API. I am not very familiar with the Fusion360 API, so I'll ask my colleague to come back with an answer

Comment: That will be great.